# usage of global variable on C#

Tags: c#, variables, global, void

So I don't know the terminology of C#.
What I am trying to do is I have 2 static voids

```
    static void SelectProduct() {
        double moneyamount = 0;

        int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (selection == 1) {
            moneyamount = 1.50;       
        }

        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + moneyamount);
        InsertCoin();
    }
    static void InsertCoin() {

        Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);
    }
```

My problem is I want to use `moneyamount` in `InsertCoin void`.
When I assign double moneyamount just right after class It gives an error.
I cannot return moneyamount as it is static. and I have to use static as i need to recall it.
So what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe make your moneyamount as static too.

```
static double moneyamount = 0;
static void SelectProduct() {
    moneyamount = 0;

    int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (selection == 1) {
        moneyamount = 1.50;       
    }

    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + moneyamount);
    InsertCoin();
}
static void InsertCoin() {

    Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

**Option 1:** Pass moneyAmount as a parameter to InsertCoin(), i.e.

```
static void InsertCoin(double moneyAmount)...
```

then call it from SelectProduct as

```
InsertCoin(moneyAmount);
```

**Option 2:** Simple declare your global variable as static, i.e.

```
static double moneyAmount = 0;

static void SelectProduct()...

static void InsertCoin()...
```

Comment: +1, this is arguably a better solution as it's beginning to getting rid of all these pointless `static`s.

Comment: You can look at my sample for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices here.  You can either define moneyamount as a global variable outside of your 2 methods and have it available for both methods, or you declare it like you did and just pass it to the InsertCoin method.

**Scenario 1:**

```
static double moneyamount = 0;

static void SelectProduct()
{
     int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if (selection == 1)
     {
          moneyamount = 1.50;
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + moneyamount); 
}

static void InsertCoin()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
static void SelectProduct()
{
     double moneyamount = 0;
     int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if (selection == 1)
     {
          moneyamount = 1.50;
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + moneyamount);
     InsertCoin(moneyamount);
}

static void InsertCoin(double moneyamount)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);
}
```

I hope this helps.  Shout if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to methods. Please google for "c# functions syntax"

```
 static void InsertCoin(double moneyAmount) 
 {          
   Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `moneyamount` in the class, not in the class method, and make it `static` too. That way static methods in the same class can access your static variable `moneyamount`.

Declaring the method as `static` means the method is part of a class, and can be access directly from another class. Without `static`, that become part of the object instance, and can be accessed through an object. Hence a static method access a static variable:

```
static string fooString;
static void FooMethod()
{
    fooString = "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the static property of `MoneyAmount`

```
static double MoneyAmount
{get; set;}

static void SelectProduct() 
{
    MoneyAmount= 0;

    int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (selection == 1) {
        MoneyAmount = 1.50;       
    }

    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + MoneyAmount);
    InsertCoin();
}

static void InsertCoin() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + MoneyAmount);
}
```

Or you can make parameter to `InsertCoin()`

```
static void SelectProduct() 
{
    double moneyamount = 0;

    int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (selection == 1) {
        moneyamount = 1.50;       
    }

    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your drink costs $" + moneyamount);
    InsertCoin();
}

static void InsertCoin(double moneyamount) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Balance of cost $" + moneyamount);
}
```

On another note;

> I cannot return `moneyamount` as it is static

Why can't you do that?

```
static double SelectProduct()
{
...
return moneyamount;
}
```